# How to change matplotlib axes so that that it does not display in scientific notation?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib

How to change matplotlib axes so that that it does not display in scientific notation? (i.e. displaying 626.70 ... 626.77 in this case)
I tried changing the x ticks by doing `ax.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(626.720, 626.727, 0.001))`, but the axes is all crammed on the left hand side.

Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x_formatter = matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter(useOffset=False)
x_formatter.set_scientific(False)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(x_formatter)
```